# python get data from an already opened file

Tags: python, file, inputstream

```
f=open("vmi","w")
f.write("asdf")
import os
os.path.getsize("vmi")
#0 byte
f.close()
os.path.getsize("vmi")
# 4 bytes
```

Where I can find lost 4 bytes, 
on program execution, before file is closed?

Comment: The Python manual states explicitly: "Due to buffering, the string may not actually show up in the file until the `flush()` or `close()` method is called."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try to flush out the data first:

```
f.flush()
```

Why would you need to do this? Well, the OS will try to buffer writes to files for performance reasons - it is a lot slower to write 1024 bytes one at a time than just write out the whole buffer. So, whenever you are working with a file / pipe / socket kind of thing, keep in mind that it might be buffering writes and that you will need to `flush` first.

When you closed the file, it was flushed automatically.

Comment: Also, If you write to a file and then read back from it, you usually need to flush in between the write and read.

Comment: If the OS is buffering the file, why doesn't the OS know about it and report the buffered size of the file? Sounds more like it's python doing the buffering.

Comment: i'm not sure. the python docs mention `stdio` and `fflush`. i get your point, but i don't think that is how it works...

Comment: sorry, may be it's wrong idea, but i expect to get something like this:
    >>> f.flush(); 
    >>> f.read()
    # and as a result - 'smth error text'

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
import os
f = open("vmi", "w")
f.write("asdf")
f.flush()
os.path.getsize("vmi")
#4 byte
f.close()
os.path.getsize("vmi")
# 4 bytes
```

Comment: I don't want just to getsize() give me real size, but I want to get the full data from stderr, when the program is running